# Mostrar DIV por um ID

Tags: php, html

Estou querendo adicionar essa mensagem em uma página chamada de contato.php

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

Essa mensagem deverá aparecer quando a mensagem for enviada corretamente através de uma página chamada envia.php que possui vinculação com o PHPMailer. Como eu faço para esse arquivo mostrar essa mensagem no contato.php quando a mensagem for enviada corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Na página `envia.php`, após enviar o e-mail corretamente crie uma sessão:

```
 /*----- Função PHPMailer ------*/
 $enviado = $mail->Send();

 if ($enviado) {
    $_SESSION['EmailEnviado']=1; /*Caso o e-mail seja enviado com sucesso*/
 } else {
    $_SESSION['EmailEnviado']=0;
 }

header("Location: contato.php"); /*redireciona para contato.php*/
```

Na página `contato.php`, no inicio da página antes de qualquer HTML faça:

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['EmailEnviado'])) { /*Verfica session do e-mail*/
      $_SESSION['EmailEnviado']=0;
    }
?>
```

Na parte da mensagem verifique a session do e-mail:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['EmailEnviado']==1){?> /*Mostra Mensagem caso e-mail enviado*/
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
    </div>
 <?php }$_SESSION['EmailEnviado']=0;?> /*Reseta o valor da session*/
```